# XNA : How to use double value within Draw() method instead of float to get precise rotation?

Tags: c#, rotation, xna, double, draw

I would like to draw an oriented line toward a target depending on a specific angle calculated via tangent which will give a radian result.

As far as i know, to get a precise rotation, i have to use a `double` value in order to express a correct radian.
However, [`Spritebatch.Draw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196416%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) requires a `float` value as rotation:

```
public void Draw (
         Texture2D texture,
         Vector2 position,
         Nullable<Rectangle> sourceRectangle,
         Color color,
         **float rotation,**
         Vector2 origin,
         float scale,
         SpriteEffects effects,
         float layerDepth
)
```

If i convert the `double` value to `float`, the angle is incorrect and it will miss the target i am expecting to intersect.

**How can i draw the correct oriented line based on my `double` instead of `float`?**

The best case could be to trace the line inside the `Update()` instead of the `Draw()` but i think i'm not enough experienced to achieve that with a thing like `Vector2.Transform()` because i can't visualize what it will do and i can't find a proper noob-oriented explanation.

Comment: I highly doubt you need `double`.  I suspect your problem lies elsewhere in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're going to be able to get any more precise than that. You're using XNA, which means you're stuck using XNA's API. There is no overload for `Draw` that takes a `double` there. Just `float`.

Graphics cards don't have great support for doubles anyway. Consider this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509646%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

That talks about the different scalar types that HLSL can support. It does list `double` as an option, but it states that

> You cannot use double precision values as inputs and outputs for a stream.

XNA is actually a rather thin wrapper over DirectX, so I wouldn't expect it to support much in the way of doubles. In fact, I'm having a hard time thinking of *any* game framework that uses `double`. WPF is the closest I can think of, and that's a UI framework, not a game dev framework.

For the purpose of a video game, it's rather rare that `float` isn't precise enough for what you're doing. I suspect that there's either a separate, genuine bug that's preventing you from getting things accurate enough (which even `double` wouldn't save you with), or an entirely different approach that you could take that would get you around it.

I know you already thought of this, but if precision is really the only problem here, you could do the math separately, ahead of time, and then just convert it to a float when you pass it in to the `Draw` call.

Comment: WPF ultimately uses DirectX so I suspect it too will suffer from fidelity loss, otherwise great answer! :)